# Ruby class inheritance of included gems

Tags: ruby, inheritance, class

```
class Foo
  require 'somegem'
end

class Bar < Foo
 def to_s
  puts Somegem.somemethod
 end
end
```

Why is this not working/how can I get something like this to work?

Comment: require and include are two different things. Which one do you want to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat somegem.rb

class Somegem
  def self.somemethod
    "somemethod"
  end
end

$ cat foo.rb

class Foo
  require 'somegem'
end

class Bar < Foo
 def to_s
  puts Somegem.somemethod
 end
end

bar = Bar.new()
bar.to_s

$ ruby foo.rb
somemethod
```

But I'm not exactly sure though, what you tried to accomplish ...